# PATCH-endpoint name REST API

Tags: java, spring, api, rest

I use Java 11 and Spring Boot 2.
I have a simple CRUD microservice that operates on one resource, for example "Person", which has about 10 fields. I have following 4 endpoints:

Method **GET**: /v1/person/{id}

Method **POST**: /v1/person

Method **PATCH**: /v1/person/{id}/email

Method **DELETE**: /v1/person/{id}

The PATCH endpoint from a business point of view can only be called for an operation to update one field - 'email', the value of which is passed in the request body.

So, question is:

1. Is it OK, that in URI of PATCH-method I have /email, or I must have:/v1/person/{id}. Is it bad practice to do so, because there are any reasons not to do that?

From my point of you it looks not so bad, because it's immediately clear which property(field) we want and we CAN to update, but I doubt that this does not violate the rest-approach to naming endpoints.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Patch is like PUT/POST method, it has request body where you can send only the changed fields. Think there are hundreds of fields, are you going to create 100of the rest endpoints for them. Definitely that's not a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If there are hundreds of fields and if I need to update any of the different fields often, then I would use one PATCH method and Map in RequestBody. 
But in this service I have this method only for update one field and in method argument, so in RequestBody I have DTO called EmailHolder which contains only one field - String email, so this endpoint can only be used for email updating.  
It's assumed that in service only one field will be updated, others will not and it will be the only 1 patch method for that resource. So than can I call with /email at the end or better not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the perspective of REST, both PATCH and PUT should use the same target-resource as the GET that is used to fetch a representation of the resource.

That's the uniform interface constraint: all resources understand messages the same way, and therefore any client that can talk to one of them can talk to all of the others.

BUT...

You have a lot of freedom in how you define your *resources*.  The mapping of your resource model to your data model does *not* have to be one to one.  Taking a graph or related information and spreading it to several different resources is *normal*.  (You have to understand the trade offs you are making, of course.)

So if you want to have the user profile available via one resource, and contact addresses available via a different address, that's fine.  Or you can combine them.  Or you can have three resources - one with each isolated, and a third where they are combined.  It's all *fine* (again, tradeoffs).

---

One example of the kind of trade off you run into: as far as a general purpose component is concerned, there is no relationship implied between `/v1/person/1` and `/v1/person/1/email`, in exactly the same way there is no relationship implied between `/v1/person/1` and `/questions/66443217/patch-endpoint-name-rest-api`.

So when you propose a change to `/v1/person/1/email`, general purpose components are not going to know that implies a change to `/v1/person/1`.  Similarly, general purpose components are not going to assume that `DELETE /v1/person/1` has any effect at all on `/v1/person/1/email`.

Which is great! when the resources really are unrelated.  But might offer you some cache invalidation problems when the two resources are related.

That's why we have to sit down and do the work of designing our resource model, so that we get sensible behaviors when general purpose components in the "transfer of documents over a network" domain send us requests and interpret our responses.

---

> I'm not quite sure that I understand correctly what you mean by the: 'general purpose component'.

Things that understand HTTP metadata, without necessarily understanding the semantics of your specific resources.  Examples would include

- browsers
- remote web authoring tools
- caches
- spiders/crawlers
- proxies

All of these are things that understand the HTTP application, without necessarily understanding anything about the *documents* that we are transferring across the network, or the meanings that they carry.

> I don't understand why when we propose a change to /v1/person/1/email, general purpose components are not going to know that implies a change to /v1/person/1

Because that's not how HTTP works.  Identifiers are just identifiers; the fact that the spellings overlap doesn't mean anything.

Which is good, in the sense that we can choose identifier spellings that make things easier for the human beings trying to read them.  But human beings will see relationships between identifiers that the machines don't see.

If you want to describe the relationship between resources so that the machines can understand them, then the correct mechanism to use is [Web Linking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8288); if you want to announce that changes to this resource also invalidate that resource, then you need something like [Linked Cache Invalidation](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-nottingham-linked-cache-inv-02.html)... alas, LCI doesn't appear to have survived long enough to be standardized, [registered](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), and adopted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry, but I'm not quite sure that I understand correctly what you mean by the: 'general purpose component' and why when we propose a change to /v1/person/1/email, general purpose components are not going to know that implies a change to /v1/person/1.

Comment: Thanks for your additions! One moment that 'email' is just a field in object Person, so private String email in class Person. So 'email' is not a resource (not a child of Person), therefore they have not parent-child relationship.
Specifically in this case is it better say in url, that here you can update only email or it's redundant? Because it seems to me that make simple PATCH /v1/person/{id} can be misleading, that something else can be updated besides the email. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> In addition to utilizing the HTTP verbs appropriately, resource naming
> is arguably the most debated and most important concept to grasp when
> creating an understandable, easily leveraged Web service API. When
> resources are named well, an API is intuitive and easy to use. Done
> poorly, that same API can feel klutzy and be difficult to use and
> understand. Below are a few tips to get you going when creating the
> resource URIs for your new API.

this document is based on restful, but explain very good the best practices por resourcing naming [RESTFul Resource Naming](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html)